# How to decoupling related services

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decoupling

My project has a Product entity, and its stock is computed by its historic of sales(Order), loss, replacement... When a order is placed, the system should generate a stock line automatically. But I don't know if it's right the coupling I've done on SaveOrder method is correct. I will be using dependency injection to supply concrete classes for my interfaces. How would I decoupling OrderService and StockService?

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CurrentStock
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Historic.Sum(s => s.Quantity);
        }
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Historic { get; set; }
}


public class Stock
{
    public int StockID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Historic { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public interface IOrderService
{
    void PlaceOrder(Order order);
}
public interface IOrderRepository
{
    void Insert(Order order);
}

public interface IStockService
{
    void SaveStock(Stock stock);
}

public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    private readonly IOrderRepository repository;
    private readonly IStockService stockService;
    public OrderService(IOrderRepository repository, IStockService stockService)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.stockService = stockService;
    }

    public void SaveOrder(Order order)
    {
        this.repository.Insert(order);

        Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.ProductID = order.ProductID;
        stock.Date = order.Date;
        stock.Quantity = -1 * order.Quantity
        stock.Historic = "Order number " + order.OrderID;
        this.stockService.SaveStock(stock);
    }
}
```

Comment: You already decoupled IStockService from IOrderService. What you doing is using the IStockService within IOrderService. I just don't see anything wrong (from the decoupling point of view) with this code.

Comment: Indeed, unless StockService has a dependency on IOrderService, this implementation is fine.